# Mysql replication not rewriting the database name

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I'm replicating two database tables in two databases in the same MySql instant.

I have my.ini as:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=1
log-bin 
report-host=master-is-slave-host
log-bin=D:/wamp/logs/log_bin.log
relay-log=D:/wamp/logs/relaylog.log

replicate-same-server-id=1

binlog-do-db=test
replicate-rewrite-db=test->test2
```

And when the errors are checked it says that:

`Duplicate entry '18' for key 'PRIMARY'' on query. Default database: 'test2'. Query: 'INSERT INTO`test`.`c`(`id`,`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES (NULL, 'fff', '', '')', Error_code: 1062`

It seems that the rewrite has not worked.

Any one who has done this before?

**UPDATE**

I empty the table test.c (master) and restarted the slave. That table got repopulated with data. Where the slave table test2.c must be the one to get populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error doesn't look it relates to replication. You're attempting to insert values where you're adding in "18" where "18" already exists. As that column is the primary key, you can only have one "18".

I doubt that query would even run on the primary, let alone make its way to the slave and work.

Comment: actually it is trying to write to the database test (to the master itself), which should be test2. That is why I'm getting the error as the master database table actually contains an entry with primary key 18. But my slave table is empty

Comment: Your replication obviously isn't working too well. Clear out the data on your slave and then resync once you have no errors on the master.

Comment: I have no data in my slave database table. Do you see any error in my my.ini settings?

Comment: The error is unrelated to the replication. Read the message.

Comment: But @peter it tells that there going to be a duplicate primary key as it is trying to add the record to the master table `test.c`, where it should be adding to the slave table `test2.c`. The primary (test.c) already contains a row with id as 18, but test2.c is empty. I don't understand.

Comment: I empty the test.c table and restarted the slave. then that table got populated (master itself got populated) not the slave test2.c table

Comment: Yes actually, you were right, I was inserting with INSERT INTO table.c()
and it should be INSERT INTO c()